# git rebase lost my changes. I have a detailed history. Any idea what went wrong?

Tags: git

Major changes gone. And for no apparent reason.

Firstly, I made my own branch my_branch form feature_branch.

I made some changes, and committed them locally.

Later I needed to pull in some changes made by others on feature_branch.  I did this with rebase.

Then I pushed my_branch to the server using force.

So far so good.

Then I did more changes, committed them, pulled feature_branch from server, rebased (for the second time), and my changes are gone.  I have the rebase logs and history logs. This is what I just didL

```
  Do some work.
$ git status
-> on my_branch with some changes.
$ git add .  // add new files and updated files.
$ git commit -m "message"
$ git status
-> on my_branch, nothing to commit
$ git push --force // send my changes to my_branch on the server.
$ git checkout feature_branch
$ git pull  // get latest changes from the server.
$ git checkout my_branch
$ git rebase feature_branch // this should merge my changes, not overwrite them!
-> bunch of merge messages and one conflict.
-> I fixed the one conflict.
```

Now at least some of my major changes are gone. The rebase command ($ git rebase feature_branch" has overwritten my changed (and committed) files with files from original for no apparent reason.  We are talking several hundred lines of code.  I have not done $ git rebase --continue yet, as I noticed it has lost my work.

If I look in bitbucket at my_branch which I pushed right before I did the rebase command, I see my changes which I pushed up.  But they are missing locally since the rebase command.

What could have gone wrong?

NOTE: no one except me has modified my_branch.

I guess I have three options now.

```
1) wipe my local git database, and try to restore from time machine.
2) try git merge --abort and hope.
3) try to get my_branch from the server again. I don't know how to do this, other than to delete my local git directory, and clone from scratch, then checkout the branch.
```

Any suggestions?

Here is a log of the offending rebase:

```
 git rebase feature_branch
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: <some old commit message1>
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M somefile1
M somefile2
M somefile3
.git/rebase-apply/patch:160: trailing whitespace.
    "xxx-keyspace-configs": [ 
.git/rebase-apply/patch:485: trailing whitespace.
        
.git/rebase-apply/patch:1258: new blank line at EOF.
+
.git/rebase-apply/patch:1299: new blank line at EOF.
+
.git/rebase-apply/patch:1341: new blank line at EOF.
+
warning: squelched 1 whitespace error
warning: 6 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging somefile1
Auto-merging somefile2
Auto-merging somefile3
Auto-merging somefile4
Applying: <some old commit message2>
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M somefile1
M simefile2
M somefile3
M somefile4
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging somefile4
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in somefile4
Auto-merging somefile3
Auto-merging somefile2
Auto-merging somefile1
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0002 xxx
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch

Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
You can instead skip this commit: run "git rebase --skip".
To abort and get back to the state before "git rebase", run "git rebase --abort".
```

If I get back to the state before the rebase, and do it again, I'll lose my changes again.

=== update ===

```
$ git reflog engage-swh
c051e4f4b (origin/my_branch, my_branch) my_branch@{0}: commit: <my last commit message>
b9275d1ae my_branch@{1}: commit: <my second from last commit message>
30a24608b my_branch@{2}: rebase finished: refs/heads/my_branch onto 732a052fd4e0a6c171b52acb84ddaf16d27956c1
11c60cd90 my_branch@{3}: commit: <my first commit message>
1b811e4b2 (feature-2019R07) my_branch@{4}: branch: Created from feature-2019R07
```

If I look at say file6 in bitbucket for branch my_branch, then look what I have locally directly after the rebase, all the lines I added are gone.  The local version is the same as the version before I made my changes. All my changes are on the remote.  The file which has been "overwritten" is not one which was merged (i.e. not in the output above)

I just tried to do

```
$ git merge --abort
```

I an attempt to get my lost work back.

This results in:

```
fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing).
```

I guess this leaves me with two options, restore a backup from time machine, or delete my project dir, clone the project again, and checkout my_branch.  The question is, how do I rebase feature_branch without it overwriting my changes again?  I assume I cannot merge, as I rebased originally.

==== update 2 ====

I just tried:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph --decorate
```

As suggested by padawin

It shows a very long list of commits by all the people who are working on feature_branch branch, along with all their branches off of of this.  There are no errors or anything which gives a clue. Here are the first few lines:

```
* a84d5dcbd (HEAD) my first commit message.
* 139d71db8 (origin/feature_branch, feature_branch) made xxx in_active
*   bedea7520 Merge branch 'feature_branch' of https://bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx-parent into feature_branch
|\  
| *   b4c06d0c8 Merge branch 'feature_branch' of https://bitbucket.org/xxx/xxx-parent into feature_branch
| |\  
| * | 7996ca962 Release Prep
* | | 76aaddfcf system config update
| |/  
|/|
```

=== update ====

I tired to finish the rebase, even though my work has been "overwritten".
I fixed the one file which was in conflict, did "$ git add ." to mark it fixed, then did "$ git rebase --continue".

I now get a bunch more errors:

```
$ git rebase --continue
Applying: <one of my commit messages>
Applying: refactored merger, added update
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M somefile1
M somefile2
M somefile3
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging somefile3
Auto-merging somefile2
Auto-merging somefile1
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in somefile1
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0003 refactored merger, added update
The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch
```

Comment: `wipe my local git database, and try to restore from time machine` stop. Don't do this. Rebase hasn't deleted anything.

Comment: Why did you use `git push --force` in the middle there? I'd say it's more likely you lost stuff there if you had to use force push.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Why would a force push lose anything?

Comment: Because if there were changes remotely that you did not have, the `--force` will have overwritten them. I'd suggest to use `--force` only if you are comfortable with it, and are sure you will not erase any work.

Comment: "*What could have gone wrong? [...] Any suggestions?*" is too vague for me (plus all the details are missing). This question seems more like the start of a conversation than a question with a specific technical answer.

Comment: Could you stop haring off about everything _but_ the actual evidence you're looking at and show some evidence of what changes you're talking about?  If you've got a screwed up history, show the history.

Comment: FYI push --force is the only way to push a branch after rebase. Noone else has edited my branch.   The main file which has lost its changes is not listed in the rebase output.

Comment: Sorry, how do I show the history?

Comment: `git log --oneline --graph --decorate`

Comment: Note, I have not lost any commits. I commited my changes, and force pushed them to bitbucket. I can see them in there. ThenI did "$ git rebase feature_branch", and the rebase command seems to have overwritten my changed files.  I have not done "git rebase --commit " yet, as I dont know what to do.

Comment: Your rebase has *stopped in the middle* due to the merge conflict. `git log` shows the in-progress rebase, not what the final result will eventually be. Use `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` to see what you have so far with a crude ASCII graphical representation; or use a viewer like `gitk` with `--all` for a fancier version; but in any case you'll probably want to finish the rebase, or decide not to do it at all, before you get too concerned here.

Comment: Are you saying that immediately after doing git rebase xxx command, before doing git rebase --continue, it is normal that some of your work is not visible in local file system?

Comment: @JohnLittle: more or less, yes. The file system shows you only the *work-tree*, not commits. `git log` and graphical viewers show you commits, in various ways. It's always important to keep in mind the difference between commits (mostly-permanent, completely unchangeable, identified by their big ugly hash IDs), the *index* (from which new commits get made: not permanent, and difficult to view directly), and the *work-tree* (where your files have their normal form: you can see and change them directly).

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- <s>why `git push --force`?</s> That's answered, and legit.
- As you are the only one who worked on the branch, look at the reflog of your branches:

  ```
  git reflog my_branch
  ```
- Run some logs to find the commits you've lost
- cherry pick them in the branches they belong to.

As per the following discussion, you had a conflict, and you are now in the middle of a rebase. You then need to stage any unstage changes that you want applied in the commit that `git rebase` is trying to apply, then run `git rebase --continue` to carry on with the rebase.

Comment: git push --force is required when you use rebase.

Comment: I might have misread, but I don't remember it was mentioned that you rebased when I answered (before the question was edited), if it was, my bad then.

Comment: I havent lost any commits. My work was committed, and appears on the server where I did a forced push. Right after pushing, I did rebase, which overwrote my changes. I have not commited the rebase yet. Nor can I get out of the rebase, is "git merge --abort" gives fatal: There is no merge to abort (MERGE_HEAD missing).

Comment: Did you run `git rebase --continue` after fixing the conflicts (and adding the resulting changes)? If not, that might be what you need.

Comment: No. as per my command line history above, the last command I did was "$ git rebase feature_branch".  I then fixed the one conflict in my IDE, then noticed that my work (which is commited to origin) has been overwritten by the rebase.  I am now stuck - dont know what to do next.  git status says "rebase in progress... your are currently rebasing branch "my_branch"  but I cant get out of it.

Comment: To be clear, I have not lost any commits. Its only rebase has lost at least some of my changes. I have not done $git rebase --continue yet.

Comment: Then `git rebase --continue` is what you need. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---continue

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a lot of pain, I think I know what the problem is. Rebase, after it has been used a few times, works in stages. during these stages, you temporarily "lose" your work until it catches up in a later stage. I had no idea this happened - I thought all was lost.

Comment: The process works as follow:
First, Git memorises all the commits in your current HEAD not in the new base you provided, then it moves your HEAD on the new base (point on which you rebase). Finally it applies all the commits memorised in step 1, one by one. If a conflict occurs at some point, it stops, asks for you to fix the conflict and waits for you to say "ok, all fixed, you can continue", which is the step described in my answer.